# Fetch data from MSSQL in dropdown using php

Tags: php, sql-server, database

In this code i am trying to fetch city names into the html dropdown. Kindly corrct me if i am wrong anywhere, it give me an error

```
<?php
        $query = Run("select city_name from City");
        echo "<select name="city-name" style="width: 210px;">";                                                            
         while ($row = mssql_num_rows($query))
         {
             echo "<option>$row->city_name</option>";   
          }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mssql_num_rows` returns the number of rows in the result set, it doesn't iterate and return individual rows. Try using `mssql_fetch_object` instead.

Comment: I am already use the same code as mention above to fetching the data from DB through mssql_num_rows

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-num-rows.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-object.php.

Answer (score 2):

use `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` insted of  `mssql_num_rows($query)`

try this one

```
 echo "<select>";
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row['city_name']."'>".$row['city_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$query = Run("select city_name from City");
        echo "<select name='city-name' style='width: 210px;'>";                                                            
         while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($query))
         {
             echo "<option>$row->city_name</option>";   
          }
        echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start a string with " then you have to escape all occurrences of " inside your string or use '.

For example:

```
echo "<select name=\"city-name\" style=\"width: 210px;\">";
```

or

```
echo '<select name="city-name" style="width: 210px;">';
```

so you don't accidently close the string.

Also like the others pointed out, you have to use

```
mysqli_fetch_array($query).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$query = Run("select `city_name` from City");
            echo "<select name='city-name' style='width: 210px;'>";                                                            
             while ($row = mssql_num_rows($query))
             {
                 echo "<option value='.$row->city_name.'>".$row->city_name."</option>";   
              }
            echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.